# How to position a graphic at the very bottom of the page

Tags: graphics, positioning

I would like to put a vector graphic on my title page at the very bottom of the page. Under the graphic must be no space left. I already searched in the internet but wasn't successful.
What I tried by now is following:

```
\vfill
    \begin{figure}[hp!]
        \begin{addmargin}[-20mm]{-15mm} % Scale picture over entire page width
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture.pdf}
        \end{addmargin}
    \end{figure}
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to do it?
P.S. I'm using the scrartcl environment and the graphicx package

---

This doesn't work. The image now isn't spanned over the entire page anymore and it is also not at the bottom. I'm not using float. Here is my code with the picture:

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}
        \Huge
        \textbf{Title text}
        
        \vspace{1.5cm}
        \normalsize
        \textbf{Author}
        
        \begin{figure}[b]
            \begin{addmargin}[-20mm]{-15mm} % Scale the image over the page width
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture}
            \end{addmargin}
        \end{figure}
    \end{center}
    \clearpage
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: The vfill has no effect on a float, you are preventing the float being placed at the bottom of the page as you used the optional argument removing the `b` option which would normally be allowed. You probably want `[!b]` or no option at all.

Comment: Removing the optional arguments caused the picture to be placed at the top of the page.  The argument [!b] and [b] didn't help too - no effect with this. Removing the \vfill had also no effect - so this can be omitted indeed.

Comment: It seems, the picture always stays over the footer area of the page. How can I take off the footer just for this page? This might solve my problem.

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: but I suspect that your image is not really a float at all so you should not be using `figure` and instead be using `\thispagestyle{a-custom-pagestyle with an image instead of page number}`

Comment: The `\thispagestyle{empty}`didn't work. How can I use `\thispagestyle{a-custom-pagestyle with an image instead of page number}`? Do you have an example on how to get a picture instead the page number?

Comment: @techie  Don't use `\begin{figure}`... `end{figure}`  just include the image last on the page you developing for the title

Comment: If I omit the `begin{figure} .. end{figure}` the picture gets up to the position after the text (the title).

Answer (score 2):

for a title page you do not want a float, use

```
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
Some title text

\vspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\clearpage
```

Comment: @techie you have provided no example, you will need `[width=\linewidth]` if you want it full width of course (and possibly \noindent depending on your document)